# why I can't encode and decode base64 with java and php?

Tags: java, php, android, base64

I encode Images on server with php and send the encoded strings to android via `get` request and decode it with java but It outputs bad base64 .

so I decided to check the base64 string on online checker but the image doesn't appear is the problem with the php encoding ?

here is the encoded image string :

```
aW1hZ2VzL21haW4vd3d3L25ldCAtIENvcHkucG5n
```

**PHP::**

```
<?php


require_once("config.php");

if(isset($_GET["m"])) {

    $dirname = "images/main/";
    $arr = array();

    $conn = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    if(!$conn) {
        echo "Error connecting to database";
        exit();
    }
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name_ FROM projects")) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($n);
        //$stmt->store_result();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows == 0) {
            echo "No Projects";
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
            exit();
        }else {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $dirname = $dirname . $row["name_"] . "/";
                $images = glob($dirname . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE);
                foreach($images as $key => $image) {
                    $image = base64_encode($image);
                    //array_push($arr, $image);
                    $dirname = "images/main/";
                    echo $image;
                    echo "/n";
                    $image = "";
                }
            }
            //echo "hi";//json_encode($arr);
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    exit();

}

?>
```

**ANDROID::**

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        String add = "http://10.0.2.2/wael/getimages.php?m=all";
        byte[] image = null;
        Bitmap real = null;
        String parsedString = "";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
        URLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(add);
            conn = url.openConnection();
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            is = httpConn.getInputStream();
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\\n");

                //image = Base64.decode(line, Base64.NO_PADDING);
                //real = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                //bitmaps.add(real);
                //image = null;
                //real = null;
            }
            String[] lines = sb.toString().split("\\n");
            for(String s: lines){
               image = Base64.decode(s, Base64.URL_SAFE);
                real = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                bitmaps.add(real);
                image = null;
                real = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                if (httpConn != null) {
                    httpConn.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "done";
    }
```

**HINT::**

all types of modes in decoding using java are not working . for exmaple `URL_SAFE` , `DEFAULT` and etc arenot working all output the same bad base64

Comment: I really don't understand the PHP snippet you provided. It makes no sense what you are doing there, as it doesn't include where $image came from, or what it is.

Comment: @IncredibleHat updated

Comment: Looks like you are trying to echo out multiple base64 encoded image paths in an output set to Content-Type: application/json. Oh dear, where to begin...

Comment: oh i am sorry i forgot it from previous try. is it the main reason for base64 bad encode ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the actual IMAGE base64 encoded and sent? Not just the path to the image, right? And if you want the actual image, then echoing multiple out from a while loop is going to create a big mash of base64 data and corrupt the images. You'd need to restructure this pretty heavily to account for multiple.

Comment: yes i only need the encoded string see this after removing the json part . the following is still not outputing an image `aW1hZ2VzL21haW4vd3d3L25ldCAtIENvcHkucG5n`

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter#

Comment: added `echo "/n"` after image but nothing yet

Comment: You're sending the literal string `images/main/www/net - Copy.png` in that base64-encoded string, and then your java attempts to turn that literal string into a bitmap. Perhaps you want to send the *content* of the file instead of the filename? Also PNGs aren't bitmaps, so you're in for a bit of trouble there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't base64 encoding an image, you are base64 encoding the path to an image.

It's like if someone said "Send me a picture of the empire state building", and then you wrote them a letter that said "A picture of the empire state building".

For example, in your comment you said

> the following is still not outputing an image aW1hZ2VzL21haW4vd3d3L25ldCAtIENvcHkucG5n

But if I do the following:

```js
console.log(atob("aW1hZ2VzL21haW4vd3d3L25ldCAtIENvcHkucG5n"))
```

when you hit run you will see

> images/main/www/net - Copy.png

Clearly, not the intended result.

In PHP, you would instead do something like this:

```
$image = file_get_contents($filename);
$b64_image_raw = base64_encode($im);      
$mime = mime_content_type($filetype)
$b64_image = "data:" . $mime . ";base64," . $b56_image_raw;
```

which will give you something like:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB0AAAAdCAMAAABhTZc9AAAAP1BMVEU7V507V50AAAA7V507V507V53///9GYaP7/P33+Pvm6vPa4O2aqM3s7/bf5O+8xd6uutigrdBfd7BNZ6c+Wp9WPQrIAAAABXRSTlP0cwDze/4T5ZQAAABkSURBVCjP3c45DoAwDETRcUiclZ37n5UoFUUyEhIVv32yNTAyuX6TGIgbJwDRiqy36kuOGlNfj6StrvpZie7KdKmw+dGqUPUcbm5PP1d9FC6mmd6uVAtf9VcFUcAStTCCgULMDXttET4Wr4wGAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC`

```js
var image = document.createElement("img")
image.src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB0AAAAdCAMAAABhTZc9AAAAP1BMVEU7V507V50AAAA7V507V507V53///9GYaP7/P33+Pvm6vPa4O2aqM3s7/bf5O+8xd6uutigrdBfd7BNZ6c+Wp9WPQrIAAAABXRSTlP0cwDze/4T5ZQAAABkSURBVCjP3c45DoAwDETRcUiclZ37n5UoFUUyEhIVv32yNTAyuX6TGIgbJwDRiqy36kuOGlNfj6StrvpZie7KdKmw+dGqUPUcbm5PP1d9FC6mmd6uVAtf9VcFUcAStTCCgULMDXttET4Wr4wGAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
document.getElementById("image").appendChild(image)
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Curious. That may work out better for him on his android side. Formatting it with the mime type and prefixes.